# JavaScript mouseup Event Being Fired Multiple Times On Single Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, mouseup

Can someone tell me why the javascript code below causes renewSession() to be called 7 times after a single click?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*").mouseup(function () {
        renewSession();
    });
});

function renewSession() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/RenewSession",
        type: "POST"
    });
}
```

Comment: The * selector is not good from performance and maintenance point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably it's because the `mouseup` event propagates up through the DOM tree, and you're applying the handler to *every* element in the document. So it'll fire on the first element, and then the parent and so on until it gets to the `html` (or the `body`, I can never quite remember without checking every time).

You could use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*").mouseup(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        renewSession();
    });
});
```

To prevent the multiple calls.

---

**Edited** to address comment from thiag0:

> Thanks for the quick response...what I am trying to do is call renewSession() every time the user clicks on the site to keep the session alive. This solution prevents the renewSession from getting called multiple times in a single click but prevents the actual intent of the user's click from firing. Anyway to get around this?

You could just target the `body` element; so long as events are allowed to propagate through the DOM tree (so long as you're not calling `event.stopPropagation()` on elements between the element clicked on (or 'mouseup'-ed) then the event(s) will propagate to the `body`. So I'd suggest using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").mouseup(function () {
        renewSession();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...what I am trying to do is call renewSession() every time the user clicks on the site to keep the session alive.  This solution prevents the renewSession from getting called multiple times in a single click but prevents the actual intent of the user's click from firing.  Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The * selctor matches 7 elements...

Events in html bubble up the DOM tree, unless explicitly told to stop, and hence the event will be triggered for each element going up the tree that matches the selector (in this case all of them!).

If this is not your intended behaviour either use a more specific selector, or call the [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...what I am trying to do is call renewSession() every time the user clicks on the site to keep the session alive. This solution prevents the renewSession from getting called multiple times in a single click but prevents the actual intent of the user's click from firing. Any way to get around this?